# Loopback storage error - Path does not exist: undefined

Tags: rackspace-cloud, loopbackjs, strongloop

Please help

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Storage+service

I want to set it to upload into the container rackspace

but an error after slc run

http://prntscr.com/69uvcb

```
    /root/example-file-storage/node_modules/loopback-component-storage/lib/providers/filesystem/index.js:25
    throw new Error('FileSystemProvider: Path does not exist: ' + this.root);
          ^
Error: FileSystemProvider: Path does not exist: undefined
```

my config

```
/server/datasources.json 

 "rackspace": {
    "name": "rackspace",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "username": "*****",
    "apiKey": "*****************************",
    "region": "IAD"
  }

root@rest:~/lifefilm/server# slc -v
strongloop v2.10.3 (node v0.10.36)
├── strong-arc@1.1.0
├── strong-build@1.0.3 (5a43a57)
├─┬ strong-supervisor@1.4.1 (c945bd1)
│ └── strong-agent@1.3.2
├── node-inspector@0.7.4
├── strong-deploy@1.1.4 (5e25e21)
├── strong-pm@1.7.2 (315d448)
├── strong-registry@1.1.4 (aab3dbb)
├── nodefly-register@0.3.3
└── generator-loopback@1.7.3 (9dc370f)
```

Comment: i resolve this.... need add line when use rackspace - root: '/tmp/storage'

Comment: and need   authUrl: 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com' , https://gist.github.com/rosskukulinski/6071fc347b9ab1223707

Comment: You should answer the question yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line when use rackspace

```
...
root: '/tmp/storage',
authUrl: 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com',
...
```

example: gist.github.com/rosskukulinski/6071fc347b9ab1223707